# SQL- Multiple Clauses for Filter

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

So I'm not completely sure it should be a WHERE statement vs a subclause, vs CASE. Frankly, I'm still trying to learn the use cases of subclause and CASE.

What I'd like at the end is a count of their attendance and a sum of their invoices paid within a certain time frame.

I get an error when trying to "ERROR: syntax error at or near "from" Position: 349"

Expected output: Child Name, Center ID, Classroom name, Attendance count, the sum of Invoices, Date,

I'm joining multiple tables and want to filter for both attendance within a certain date, and invoices paid within a certain date:

```
select accounts.fname as first_name, accounts.lname as last_name, accounts.dob, centers.label, classrooms.label as classroom_label, 
count(*) as no_of_days_attended, sum(transactions.amount / 100.0) as sum_of_transactions_paid, 
from daily_reports
join account_classrooms
on daily_reports.account_classroom_id = account_classrooms.id
join accounts
on account_classrooms.account_id = accounts.id
join classrooms
on account_classrooms.classroom_id = classrooms.id
join centers
on classrooms.center_id = centers.id
join invoices
on centers.id = invoices.center_id
join transactions
on transactions.invoice_id = invoices.id
where daily_reports.ref_date and transactions.created_at > {{start_date}} and daily_reports.ref_date and transactions.created_at < {{end_date}} and centers.id = {{center_id}}
group by daily_reports.account_classroom_id, accounts.id, classrooms.id, centers.id,
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you didn't ask a question , but nevertheless provide sample data and desired output

Comment: query seems ok, what do expect as output?

Comment: Wouldn't a "daily_reports.ref_date BETWEEN Time1 AND Time2  AND transactions.created_at BETWEEN Time1 AND Time2" increase readability ?

Comment: Heya Thanks for asking for clarification! I get an error when trying to "ERROR: syntax error at or near "from" Position: 349" 
@GordonLinoff 

Expected output:

Child Name, Center ID, Classroom name, Attendance count, the sum of Invoices, Date,

Comment: 1) You have an extra comma at the end of your GROUP BY statement 2) The columns in your SELECT clause must either be in the GROUP BY clause or be aggregate functions - your SELECT and GROUP BY clauses are not in sync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple issues going on.

First, there's an extra comma right before your FROM clause, and another at the end of GROUP BY. Your GROUP BY columns do not appear in your SELECT statement, so that's not going to work. When doing an aggregation (SUM(), MAX(), etc) the engine has to know which columns by which to group the aggregation. These are the columns in your SELECT list.

Second, you can't evaluate two columns at once like this:

```
daily_reports.ref_date and transactions.created_at > {{start_date}}
```

If you did, you'd get this error:

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.
```

Each evaluation has to be atomic. In this example, it would have to be something like this:

```
daily_reports.ref_date > {{start_date}} and transactions.created_at > {{start_date}}
```

However, the WHERE clause could be cleaned up even further by using the BETWEEN operator. Also, it is better practice to not use implicit JOIN. Define the type of JOIN in your code (e.g. INNER JOIN).

I have applied aliases, formatted the code and applied the BETWEEN operator. See if this works for you. As you can see, when code is well formatted, it's more readable, and easier to spot problems.

```
SELECT  a.fname AS first_name
        ,a.lname AS last_name
        ,a.dob
        ,cn.label
        ,cl.label AS classroom_label
        ,COUNT(*) AS no_of_days_attended
        ,SUM(t.amount / 100.0) AS sum_of_transactions_paid
FROM    daily_reports AS dr
        INNER JOIN account_classrooms AS ac ON dr.account_classroom_id = ac.id
        INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON ac.account_id = a.id
        INNER JOIN classrooms AS cl ON ac.classroom_id = cl.id
        INNER JOIN centers AS cn ON cl.center_id = cn.id
        INNER JOIN invoices AS i ON cn.id = i.center_id
        INNER JOIN transactions AS t ON t.invoice_id = i.invoices.id
WHERE   dr.ref_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
        AND t.created_at BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
        AND cn.id = @center_id
GROUP BY
        a.fname
        ,a.lname
        ,a.dob
        ,cn.label
```

Comment: Thanks Mike!!
Much Appreciated, will try it out! 
Defintiely struggling with syntax and best practices :)

Comment: If this helped, please mark as answer by clicking the check icon :-)